# Predictive classification when only ranks are observable

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, ranking, censoring

I am taking part in a classification challenge (classes are 0 and 1) where the inputs are encrypted (because these are expensive financial data). 
As the encryption is order-preserving I can only use the fact that e.g.
$$
x_1 > x_2
$$
but not 
$$
d = x_1-x_2
$$

Besides trees, which machine learning algorithms give sound models under these circumstances?

EDIT: I assume that neural nets, SVM or logistic regression are not appropriate in this setting as they use linear transformations $b \cdot x$ which I can not apply as I don't have the "numerical structure" for this.

EDIT 2:
I am given data of the following form:
$$
(0.2,0.1,0.5,0);
(0.1,0.2,0.3,1); (0.02,0.7,0.33,1)
$$
and thousands of rows of them (and in my application more columns). In this example the first 3 entries are inputs and the 4th one is the target. 
All clumns consist of 1001 unique values in the range [0,1]. So I really think that only comparisons are possible.

I am sorry if my question was not formulated precisely enough ... I hope now the problem is clearer!

Comment: What do you mean by "dedicated?"

Comment: Well, I mean a model or algorithm classifies based on ranks of numerical data. Would you propose another wording?

Comment: I know I can use a classical CART. I was just wondering whether there is a special approeach that I am not aware of.

Comment: With @DJohnson I still wonder what you mean by "dedicated" because literally *any* procedure that works on numerical data will work, unchanged, when applied to ranks.

Comment: I don't know of any algorithms specifically designed to handle ranked inputs like this, but something like a decision tree would probably work well - for continuous input it basically selects a threshold to branch on which is essentially the same as selecting which rank to branch on.

Comment: It looks like I need to repeat the point in a previous comment: *of course* you can apply linear transformations--and any other numerical procedure you like--to these data.  Ranks are numbers!

Comment: @roundsquare I agree on trees, I wonder what else would work? Do you have any material about encoders? Can I change the representation from ordered data to something else?

Comment: @whuber: I added some edits about the data structure above. The data comes from encryption, thus I get elements on a finite set, 1001 unique values in each column in the range [0,1]. Addition is not supported. If I work with ranks then distsances could be introduced that are not present in the "real" data. rank 1 and 2 are not as close as rank 10 and 11. So I wonder whether using ranks directly is valid.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "addition is not supported."  If you are suggesting that operations like sums, means, etc. on these numbers is meaningless, then that's just not correct--and might lie at the heart of your question. You might enjoy reading FM Lord's [On the Statistical Treatment of Football Numbers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=on+the+statistical+treatment+of+football+numbers).

Comment: @whuber right ... as the numbers are the result of an encryption I wonder whether it is corect to sum them up. Say 0.6 and 0.7 - If I sum them up then I get 1.1- if 0.6 is somehow the encryption of 10 and 0.7 is the encryption of 11 then it is not clear that 1.1 is the encryption of 21.In fact this will not be true as then we could call the encryption homomorphic - which they say it is not. This is at the very heart of my question - you are right. Thanks for the link, I will read it and hopefully understand the problem better. The site will also post something in their blog soon, they say.

Comment: Because the "encryption is order-preserving" you will be just fine.

Comment: @whuber a final comment: would you say that any (at least the common) algorithms (SVM, Neural net, logistic reg.) work on the data - because the encryption is order preserving? I will read the paper ...maybe the answer is written there ;)

Comment: Since I don't have the data, I cannot honestly give an opinion on whether any particular procedure will work--but I can say that the nature of these data does not appear to rule out any procedures from consideration.  Yes, the answer should be clear in that paper (which is very accessible and non-mathematical, by the way).

Comment: @whuber thanks a lot, I really enjoyed the reading your link. I am like the prof that did not like doing statistics on ordinal numbers. Do you have any reference that covers this cardinal/ordinal number "equivalence in mathematical terms .. or is it just clear?

Comment: See Velleman and Wilkinson (1993), [Nominal, Ordinal, Interval, and Ratio Typologies are Misleading](https://www.google.com/search?q=wilkinson+ordinal+nominal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: @whuber great, I will read this next. If you would like to formulate a short answer then I would accept it. Being at peace with statistics on ordinal numbers seems to be the key.

Comment: Are the ranks ranking the data only within rows, only within columns or across rows *and* columns?

Comment: @RichardHardy the site does not give too much info about their encryption but I assume that the ranking holds accross rows. We have the features in the columns and the ranking should say that if $e_{i,j} > e{k,j}$ (encrypted elements of the same col j) then the decrypted data have this relation too. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @Richard, yes, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to better understand the problem I think it is worth explaining the main idea of how order-preserving cryptography works.

Imagine that we have column vector $\mathbf{x}$ than we want to encrypt. The encryption function is  $f(\cdot)$ and it is monotonically increasing, and potentially with varying slope.

The cipher text of $\mathbf{x}$ is $\mathbf{y}=f(\mathbf{x})$, and has the following properties

- if $x_1 \geq x_2$ then $y_1 \geq y_2$
- if $x_2 = x_2$ then $y_2 = y_2$ (this is usually prevented)
- $d(x_1,x_2) \neq d(y_1,y_2)$
- if  $d(x_1,x_2) \geq d(x_3,x_4)$ does not give information about  $d(y_1,y_2)$, and $d(y_3,y_4)$

The second property can be prevented by adding noise to $\mathbf{x}$. For example if $x_i$ is an integer between $[0,9]$. Then, $\hat{\mathbf{x}}=10\times\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{n}$, where $\mathbf{n}$ is vector a of random integer between  $[0,9]$. This transformation preserves the ordering in $\hat{\mathbf{y}}=f(\hat{\mathbf{x}})$, but removes the identification of attributes with the same value.

Given that I think you should stick to tree based classifiers such as random forest.

Comment: It must be the noise term that makes some approaches harder than without encryption. Is there are chance to get rid of the noise? Aren't there approeaches in deep learning (DL) to get rid of noise? I am not familiar enough with DL ... RBMs? Autoencoding? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use order to predict the binary outcome since if a model trained on your data is applied to totally unseen data which was collected in a slightly different way (not sure how that data was collected) then it's going to perform very badly.

Moreover, such "golden features" based on data ordering are sometimes a result of data leaks and you do not want to train your model on such data for the reason given above.

Comment: If the relative position of future or test data can be seen relative to the training data ordering, this might be less of an issue

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reasons why "it's going to perform very badly"?  I see no basis for such a pessimistic conclusion in general.  Moreover, in this situation raw performance may be irrelevant: one only has to outperform the competition.

Comment: OK, perhaps I worded my answer in a wrong way. I recently took part in a ML competition where 3 teams significantly outperformed the rest. As it turned out, there was a data leak present and the teams - not knowingly - exploited it. It was a data ordering issue. After the competition finished the issue became clear and we had a discussion about it. Now, I think that it would perform badly (provided it is indeed data leak) because it is fit to a feature which would not exist in real-world data it would be used on, hence its predictive power would be low. I fully agree with your last statement.

Comment: I have 90K training data and 30K test data. The ordering on training will not work for test I assume. Just comparisons can be applied. And yes: it is good to be better than others but parts of the predictions are used to invest so the predictions should be accurate by themselves.